# Compensation for flight change made by the airline

Tags: airlines, compensation, qantas

I have a flight from São Paulo (Brazil) to Auckland (New Zealand). It's a long flight but I choose Qantas because it had the best duration for the money.

This flight was going to take 19h40, and now they changed it and it's going to take 21h10. It's not much more, but given that it's already a very long flight and I've paid for this specific flight because it took less time, do they owe me any compensation?

I could have picked another airline, I can't prove anything because fares & details have changed.

---

Edit - Flight information

It seems they changed the flight from Santiago to Auckland, I'm staying more time at the Santiago airport and the Santiago-Auckland flight was either delayed or overbooked, I don't know.

Comment: I think you are changing planes in Santiago. It would have been helpful if you mentioned this, and any additional details about your flights.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At best you can ask for a refund but no compensation.

Let's look at the [Qantas Conditions of Carriage](http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/conditions-carriage-full/global/en#jump9)

> We will use our reasonable endeavours to operate in accordance with our published schedules. However, we do not guarantee the flight times and they do not form part of your contract of carriage with us.
>
> If, due to circumstances within our control, after you buy your Ticket we make a significant change to the scheduled departure time of your flight or the flight is cancelled, we will:
>
> rebook you on the next available flight (or combination of flights) on our services to your booked destination at no additional cost to you

[or]

> alternatively, at your option, refund the applicable fare

Comment: (+1) On top of that, the OP can ask for a small compensation for the extra time he has to spend in Santiago, such as drinks or snacks. This will probably be granted.